# how to stop the youtube video playing in Ionic App

Tags: youtube, ionic-framework

I am using IFrame for playing youtube video. It works fine but I want to stop it on button click. How to do it. Please help.

```
 <div class="padding-css">
     <iframe ng-model="myframe" class="frameclass" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CR5zjazP3hg?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>   
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create iframe through java script and control player through buttons as stop.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

For more details you can go through this link.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started

Comment: ohk... but how to do it with angularjs?

Comment: make a service in angular js like youtubeService and write function in that service.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Ionic2

```
ionViewWillLeave() {
    let listaFrames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
    for (var index = 0; index < listaFrames.length; index++) {
        let iframe = listaFrames[index].contentWindow;          
        iframe.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*');
     }
}
```

Don't forget to enable JS at the end of the video link *?enablejsapi=1

Comment: Its not working. Can you show the full code.  I want to exit my app on click of lock button .